# Alguém sabe como converto variável int para bool?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, operadores

As variáveis L seriam lados de um triângulos, eu as coloquei como int e estou tentando converter para bool, vi algumas pessoas dizendo que isso não é possível, então qual tipo de variável irei usar e o que farei agora?(coloquei apenas um pedaço do código devido as limitações da pergunta)

```
    EQ = (L1 = L2) & (L2 = L3);
    ES = (L1 != L3); (L2 != L3) & (L3 != L1);
    TRI = (L1 < L2 + L3); (L2 < L1 + L3) & (L3 < L1 + L2);
    Console.WriteLine("Pode se formar um triângulo?, " + TRI);
    Console.WriteLine("O triângulo é EQUILÁTERO?, " + EQ);
    Console.WriteLine("O triângulo é ESCALENO?, " + ES);
    Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo visto seu erro está sendo usar sintaxe de atribuição `L1 = L2` (*"L1 recebe o valor de L2"*) em vez de igualdade `L1 == L2` (*"L1 é igual a L2?"*). Note que no segundo caso são dois sinais de igual juntos não um só.

Quando é uma comparação de igualdade `==` essa operação irá resultar em um valor `bool` que pode ser verdadeiro ou falso.

Já quando é uma atribuição, irá resultar em `L1`, ou seja, o operando da esquerda, que não é um `bool` e portanto não dá certo a checagem que você está querendo fazer porque o operador `&` que é aplicado em seguida espera algo `bool` dos dois lados.

**Obs.:** Tecnicamente falando não é certo dizer que está convertendo variáveis aqui de um tipo no outro, na verdade está fazendo uma operação de comparação entre dois inteiros (com `==` ou `!=`) e esse tipo de operação retorna um valor bool. Também comparar dois bool usando o operador `&` retorna um resultado bool. Por fim, atribuições usando `=` devem ser de um tipo compatível para outro, no seu caso uma variável do tipo bool deve receber um valor do tipo bool e uma variável do tipo inteiro deve receber um valor do tipo inteiro. Há complexidades adicionais envolvendo conversão de tipos mas não vou entrar nessa parte aqui, até porque C# não é minha praia.

Comment: Entendi, então o que posso fazer para conseguir comparar essas variáveis e retornar um valor bool?

Comment: É só ler a resposta acima.

Comment: Boa, isso foi uma resposta melhor que eu tava pensando

Comment: Tudo bem, mas o que eu farei com os sinais != e <, já que ele diz que somente expressões de atribuição, chamada, incremento, diminuição e novo objeto podem ser usadas como uma instrução?
Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço, mas pelo menos uma parte do código já está resolvida(L1==L2) parou de dar erro do int em relação ao bool.

Comment: Aí já é outro problema e portanto deve ser feita outra pergunta, esta aqui está resolvida e você pode aceitar a resposta se quiser. Aqui tentamos responder perguntas de forma útil para todo mundo, não atender a problemas específicos. No seu caso como dica geral você pode parar de usar o `;` no meio da linha porque está quebrando o _statement_ em dois, que estão sendo avaliados separadamente. Se quiser combinar comparações pode fazer por exemplo `MinhaVariavelBool = (L1 < L2 + L3) & (outra coisa) & (outra coisa);` entre outras combinações. Também é possível incluir o operador `|` ou `||`.

Comment: Note também que é mais interessante usar `&&` que `&` no seu caso. Entre dois bool não faz diferença mas existe uma sutil diferença entre os dois e usar errado esconde a intenção do seu código (ou seja, o que o seu código realmente deseja fazer).